# Unknown interpolation method in function 'remap' error

Tags: python, opencv, interpolation, remap

Trying to update old python code from `cv.Remap(src,dst,map1,map2,interpolation)`
to
`remapped_image = cv2.remap(src,map1,map2,interpolation)`.
The issue is the interpolation option.
The original interpolation was `cv.INTER_LINEAR+cv.WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS+cv.WARP_INVERSE_MAP`, however, when I use that interpolation code changing all the cv to cv2, I receive a `(-5 Bad argument) Unknown Interpolation method in function 'remap'`

Comment: question requires a [mre]. -- original code is faulty already. `remap()` __can't__ take such flags in principle. it uses lookup tables. those are _not_ invertible trivially.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is a cv.WARP_INVERSE_MAP flag, which seems like not supported in opencv (at least in python version). The same error appears for cv2.INTER_LINEAR_EXACT, cv2.INTER_NEAREST_EXACT, cv2.INTER_MAX, cv2.WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS. Even though there is [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga5bb5a1fea74ea38e1a5445ca803ff121) for such flags. I checked my version of cv2 as well as installed opencv_contrib and there is still an error. It seems that these flags are not supported even in [source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4154bd06677c30475e2545cbee05906dd9a367cb/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp#L1799).

Comment: "seems like not supported"? `WARP_INVERSE_MAP` is very much supported... **but not by remap()** because that's using big lookup tables, which aren't trivially invertible. **the original code was wrong already**. why answer such an old question now? why answer in such a vague/confusing way?

Comment: Yes, I'm wrong. I faced the same error while working with cv2.warpAffine() function. Now, I tried to do reproducible example and I have the same remap error for  cv2.INTER_LINEAR_EXACT, cv2.INTER_NEAREST_EXACT, cv2.INTER_MAX. But it works for cv2.WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS and cv.WARP_INVERSE_MAP. I could delete my answer and create a new question about cv2.warpAffine(). But the behavior of opencv is the same, even though I don't use remap() directly.